# How to calculate the previous day minus the previous day and then divide by the previous day to calculate the percentage in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframelooklike this:

> open  high    low close   volume
> 2021-11-02    462.0800    464.0500    461.9200    463.76  3279694
> 2021-11-03    463.1400    466.9700    462.6800    466.61  2916130
> 2021-11-04    467.2100    468.8600    466.8400    468.75  3039933
> 2021-11-05    471.1801    472.5400    468.7900    470.40  4361065
> 2021-11-08    471.5700    472.1000    470.0800    470.89  2962977

I need to calculate the previous day minus the previous day in the open column and then divide by the previous day to calculate the percentage.

The code I wrote is as follows：

`df['open_perc'] = (df['open']-df['open'].shift(1))/df['open'].shift(1) + 1`

and this is the output:

> open  high    low close   volume  open_perc
> 2021-11-02    462.0800    464.0500    461.9200    463.76  3279694 NaN
> 2021-11-03    463.1400    466.9700    462.6800    466.61  2916130 1.002294
> 2021-11-04    467.2100    468.8600    466.8400    468.75  3039933 1.008788
> 2021-11-05    471.1801    472.5400    468.7900    470.40  4361065 1.008497
> 2021-11-08    471.5700    472.1000    470.0800    470.89  2962977 1.000827

However, I want to get "1" instend of "NaN" fo rthe first day. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive that you have no other nan values, then simply:

```
df = df.fillna(1)
```

If you are not sure about the abovementioned, then you could create temp columns:
e.g.

```
df['shifted'] = df['open'].shift(1)
df.loc[(df.index == 0),'shifted'] = 1
```

and then proceed with your percentage calculation